# From 3D array of numbers, create 2D array of disks where colour is z-component

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

I have a list of 3D coordinates. I create an array of disks using their (x,y) coordinates as:

```
list = Table[{i, j, RandomReal[]}, {i, 0, 4}, {j, 0, 4}];
list = ArrayFlatten[list, 1];
disks = {Red, Disk[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, 0.1]} & /@ list;
Graphics[disks]
```

[image: Array of red disks created with the first block of code]

How can I modify this code so that the disks sample from the ColorScheme "LightTemperatureMap" with their z-component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = Table[{i, j, RandomReal[]}, {i, 0, 4}, {j, 0, 4}];
list = ArrayFlatten[list, 1];
disks = {ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][#[[3]]], Disk[{#[[1]], [[2]]},0.1]} & /@ list;
Graphics[disks]
```

[image]